# ControlValueAccessor validation into MatDialog

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I've created a simple component that implements the `ControlValueAccessor` and `Validators` interfaces.

When I use this component in a standard form, or in another standard component, it works fine.

However, as soon as I try to open a matDialog with a templateRef containing this custom FormControl `<ut-test>`, the validation of my `ControlValueAccessor` is very strange.

In fact, the fields inside my `ControlValueAccessor` are all invalid and the `validate()` method always returns an error.

What's wrong with my development?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ut-test',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: TestComponent,
            multi: true
        },
        {
            provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
            multi: true,
            useExisting: TestComponent
        }
    ]
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor, Validators {
    prefixCtrl = new FormControl<string>('', [Validators.required]);
    suffixCtrl = new FormControl<string>('', Validators.required);
    baseline = { prefix: '', suffix: '' };
    onChange: (p: any | null) => void;

    constructor(private readonly fb: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.prefixCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(next => {
            this.baseline.prefix = next;
            this.onChange(this.baseline);
        });

        this.suffixCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(next => {
            this.baseline.suffix = next;
            this.onChange(this.baseline);
        });
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        // todo
    }

    validate(): ValidationErrors | null {
        return this.prefixCtrl?.valid && this.suffixCtrl?.valid ? null : {invalidPerson: true};
    }

    writeValue(obj: any): void {
        if (obj) {
            this.prefixCtrl.setValue(obj.prefix, {emitEvent: false});
            this.suffixCtrl.setValue(obj.suffix, {emitEvent: false});
        }
    }
}
```

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>{{ "i18n.function" | translate }}</mat-label>
    <input [formControl]="prefixCtrl" name="function" type="text" matInput placeholder="" />
    <mat-error></mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>{{ "i18n.function" | translate }}</mat-label>
    <input [formControl]="suffixCtrl" name="function" type="text" matInput placeholder="" />
    <mat-error></mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

another.component.html

```
<!-- NOT OK -->
<ng-template #testDialog>
    <ut-test [formControl]="testCtrl"></ut-test>
</ng-template>

<!-- OK -->
<ut-test [formControl]="testCtrl"></ut-test>
```

```
...

testCtrl = new FormControl({prefix: '', suffix: ''});
@ViewChild('testDialog') testDialog: TemplateRef<any>;

.... 

openReplaceRusnDialog() {
    this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(this.testDialog);
    this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => result && this.replaceRusn());
}
```

[image]